# Refresh part of JSP page in Liferay MVC portlet

Tags: jsp, jquery, liferay

I need to refresh one `table` on a page without reloading the full page. Does anyone know good method for doing this?

I created separate a `jspf` page with one table, and rendered it by Ajax request `<portlet:renderURL`>, but the page wraps in the default liferay theme. Is there another way to get the page date without the theme?

```
<portlet:renderURL var="testURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jspf/test.jspf" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<script>
$("#test-button").click(function() {
    $("#test-table").load("<%= testURL %>");
})
</script>
```

Comment: post some code which you are trying so that we can figure out something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Ajax in Liferay-MVC you should create a `resourceURL` Link and handle it in `serveResource` method in the Portlet Class.

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="testURL">
    <portlet:param name="pageAddress" value="/jspf/test.jspf" />
</portlet:resourceURL>

<script>
$("#test-button").click(function() {
    $("#test-table").load("<%= testURL %>");
})
</script>
```

then you should provide properly result in `serveResource` Method of your portlet class.
in addition you can get your parameter(pageAddress) by using `resourceRequest` Object

```
String pageAddress = resourceRequest.getParameter("pageAddress");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's return jsp as text without processing jsp-tags. `PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(pageAddress);
      dispatcher.include(request, response);`

Comment: it's better use ajax just for sending information you need, not the whole logic in the part of page, for example to load a grid you should just need to get a json from server not the logic to show a grid

Comment: Yes, but i use some liferay ui tags and updates these elements with only jquery from json is uncomfortably.